# NancyFx - Razor Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nancy, owin

#### Error while compiling view

```
Error compiling template: views/devices.cshtml

Errors:
    [CS0234] Line: 3 Column: 27 - The type or namespace name 'Services' does 
    not exist in the namespace 'Rioxo.Companion' 
    (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Details:
@using System
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using Rioxo.Companion.Services <---
```

#### web.config

```
<razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Server32" />
        <add assembly="Rioxo.Companion.Services" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Server" />
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Services" />
    </namespaces>
</razor>
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** the original problem was solved by putting the configuration in the correct .config file, for future reference, adding here you can also implement your own `IRazorConfiguration` which Nancy will automatically pick up, this means you don't need any .config registraion at all.

Example:

```
public class RazorConfig : IRazorConfiguration
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAssemblyNames()
    {
        yield return "MyWebsite.Web";
        yield return "MyWebsite.Models";
        yield return "Sandra.SimpleValidator";
        yield return "ServiceStack.Text";
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetDefaultNamespaces()
    {
        yield return "Nancy.Validation";
        yield return "System.Globalization";
        yield return "System.Collections.Generic";
        yield return "System.Linq";
        yield return "MyWebsite.Web";
        yield return "MyWebsite.Models";
        yield return "MyWebsite.Web.ViewModels";
        yield return "MyWebsite.Web.Helpers.RazorHelpers";
    }

    public bool AutoIncludeModelNamespace
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer:**

I don't actually know what `Rioxo` is and their site doesn't seem to have a download.

So I'm taking a shot here and assuming its because you haven't referenced the assembly by its name properly.

I think the name is probably `Rioxo.Companion` or `Rioxo`

So updating the `<assemblies>` section to something like:

```
<razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Server32" />
        <add assembly="Rioxo" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Server" />
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Services" />
    </namespaces>
</razor>
```

or

```
<razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Server32" />
        <add assembly="Rioxo.Companion" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Server" />
        <add namespace="Rioxo.Companion.Services" />
    </namespaces>
</razor>
```

Should fix the issue.

Comment: Rioxo is my own project I'm working on currently. I already solved the problem by putting everything inside a "app.config" instead of "web.config" (the NancyFX documentation is misleading). Now it works. Sorry for forgetting to close the question.

Comment: Oh, you were self-hosting?

Comment: @Acrotygma - just added to my answer, the code registration might be a better fit for you :)

Comment: I did not know about IRazorConfiguration. Neat!